# IF...<Sql query>....ELSE IF ....<Sql query>...Else

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-jdbc

I am trying to use query in NamedParameterJdbcTemplate by writing a query with if condition for Postgresql.

I will be passing 2 parameters to the query, store and tot_store. I tried following query but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

```
IF (:store=1)
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM store_pricing WHERE store = :store and tot_store = :tot_store ORDER BY store asc;
END
ELSE IF (:store = 2)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM store_pricing WHERE store = :store and tot_store = :tot_store ORDER BY store asc;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM store_pricing WHERE store = :store and tot_store = :tot_store ORDER BY store desc;
END
```

The error says

```
syntax error at or near "IF"
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I added the error in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL doesn't accept `IF` as a top level statement. It's not SQL-standard either.

Use `CASE ... WHEN ...`

`IF` is permitted in `PL/PgSQL` code blocks, though; see `DO` and `CREATE FUNCTION`.

In this case I'd write a single SQL statement and

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN store IN (1,2) THEN -store
  ELSE store
  END DESC
```

(untested)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mysql, there is incorrect IF statement in your code.
Correct IF syntax:

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

You need to get rid of brackets and put THEN after condition.

For example you can write such stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION SimpleCompare(n INT, m INT)
  RETURNS VARCHAR(20)

  BEGIN
    DECLARE s VARCHAR(20);

    IF n > m THEN SET s = '>';
    ELSEIF n = m THEN SET s = '=';
    ELSE SET s = '<';
    END IF;

    SET s = CONCAT(n, ' ', s, ' ', m);

    RETURN s;
  END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Note, that in Mysql there is another IF. It is a function which can be used in select statements.

Official docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

Comment: I am writing the query for postgresql. I have added that in my question.